# How can I translate my routes with VueJS?

Tags: internationalization, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-i18n

How can I translate my route with VueJS and vue-i18n?

You can check my repo here:
https://github.com/polikin/vuejs-boilerplate/

Ex:

```
/en/about-us
/fr/a-propos
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far I know Vue-i18n doesn't do it out of the box. But you can use route aliases:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/en/about-us', component: YourComponent, alias: '/fr/a-propos' }
  ]
})
```

`alias` can also be an array.

In case you would go for [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) - there is a [nuxt-i18n](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n) module which internally uses vue-i18n but adds a ton of convenience features. It prefixes the locale of your rout so you're done.